# Can I change the color of a VF table cell dynamically?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, css, table

I have a picklist called Status, displayed in a Visualforce table with fields like ..

1. Closed
2. Open
3. Critical

   ```
     <div id="col1">
       <apex:column >
           <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>      
           <apex:outputText value="{!account.Status__c}"/>
       </apex:column>
     </div>
   ```

How can make all fields GREEN except the ones that are Critical RED?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign CSS classes dynamically based on the picklist value using `styleClass` attrubute:

```
<style>
.errorClass {
    background-color: red;
}
.normalClass {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!testObjectList}" var="item">
        <apex:column value="{!item.name}" 
                     styleClass="{!IF(item.status__c == 'Critical','errorClass','normalClass')}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!item.status__c}" 
                     styleClass="{!IF(item.status__c == 'Critical','errorClass','normalClass')}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The result page:

[image]

Comment: This is my controller... public class dataTableCon {
    List<Feedback__c> fb;
     public List<Feedback__c> getAccounts() {
        if(fb== null) fb= [select Name, Description__c, Importance__c, Resolution__c, Status__c,Owner.name from Feedback__c];
        return fb;
    }
}   <br/>So in your code does testObjectList=fb in my code?

Comment: @MnZ yes exactly

Comment: But it throws me this error .......Error: Unknown property 'dataTableCon.fb' 
Quick Fix Create Apex property 'dataTableCon.fb'
Quick Fix Create Apex method 'dataTableCon.getFb'

Comment: @MnZ You need to correct your own code by yourself.

Comment: I figured it out.   <apex:column value="{!account.Status__c}" 
                     styleClass="{!IF(account.Status__c == 'Closed','errorClass','normalClass')}"/>
          <apex:column >  This did the trick. I will update with an answer. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

Only standard style sheets can be used in apex:pageBlockTable tag in Visualforce page.
If we want to add custom style sheets we have to use apex:dataTable tag in Visualforce page.