# Change the color of the rows in the table

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I need to change the color of the row in the table to red if the school.student_to_teacher_ratio__c is less than 5 or else the default color should be green. How do I do that?

```
<apex:outputPanel id="school">
<apex:pageblock title="School Details">
  <apex:pageblockTable value="{!slist}" var="school">
       <apex:column value="{!school.name}" headerValue="School Name"/>

       <apex:column value="{!school.No_of_Students__c}" headerValue="No of Students"/>

       <apex:column value="{!school.No_of_Teachers__c}" headerValue="No of Teachers"/>

       <apex:column value="{!school.Student_to_Teacher_ratio__c }" headerValue="Student to Teacher ratio"/>

    </apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I think this link will be useful for you. [Change Cell Colors](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32853/can-i-change-the-color-of-a-vf-table-cell-dynamically).

Comment: The code in that link is giving me an error. The answer by Ashwani solved my problem partially as it changed only the color of the cell but not the entire row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use style attribute for the column cell as:

```
<apex:column value="{!school.Student_to_Teacher_ratio__c }" 
        headerValue="Student to Teacher ratio"
        style="{!IF(school.Student_to_Teacher_ratio__c>70,'background-color:green;',background-color:red;')}"/>
```

`style` applied on column tag always applied to its cell not header.

Comment: Any way how I can change the color of the entire row?

Comment: @User2529 apply same condition for each column.

Comment: The color of individual cells in each row is getting changed. Can I not just change the color of the entire row as a whole?

Comment: You cannot directly access rows

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I'll rephrase. Only the color of values in the cells are getting changed but not the entire cell itself. What do I do?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I didn't notice